# Cant open html file in browser from the terminal

Tags: bash, google-chrome, terminal

I go to the directory containing the file on terminal and enter this command
`google-chrome index.html` 
and get this error
`-bash: google-chrome: command not found`

Comment: What OS are you using? I think this is a duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/350309/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-google-chrome-from-the-terminal-in-os-x

Comment: Kind of duplicate  - not the same. This one cannot find google-chrome. The other is issuing the command with --args and not working.

Comment: If it works, mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

google-chrome not found should be self-explanatory.

Run this on terminal:

```
which google-chrome
```

Use the output as command.

In my Ubuntu, google-chrome is placed here:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

So, in my case I would run:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome index.html
```

If the output of 'which google-chrome' command is empty, you should install google-chrome first.

Considering your comment, perhaps the process has another name. With chrome running, execute in terminal:

```
ps  -ef | grep chrome
```

In my output it comes like:

username  32276 22430  0 14:03 ?        00:00:12 /opt/google/chrome/chrome

So, if I run:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome index.html
```

Chrome will start and open the index.html.

Check your output and adapt.

Comment: Ran `which google-chrome` command; no response. Chrome is installed already, in fact i am commenting from google chrome right now.

Comment: Check my edit mate. I updated it. Let me know if it helped.